# Keeping track of affected nodes in an area grid

Tags: algorithm, grid, nodes

I have a grid with different nodes on it. All nodes have a property that can be set to true or false, lets call it "lighted"

From some nodes, you can set "light". These lights have a range, and the affected nodes will have their "lighted" property set to true. As long as no light is in range, the node will stay as "lighted" false.

I have no problem setting nodes on, or checking which nodes are affected when a light is set.

But I don't know how to deal with setting lights off: if you set a light on, you know you have to set the affected nodes as lighted; but when a light is set off, some nodes might stay lighted as they could be affected by another light.

My first approach was to make each node know how many light are affecting it, and when a light is turn off, decrease the value for the affected node, and once it reaches 0 turn it off.

It seems simple, but I feel like this will clutter the code when I implement moving lights, which will have to destroy the former light and create a new one on the new position.

Can you think of a more efficient way to deal with this problem, being speed and not storage the main issue?

Details: The grid can have cells without nodes. In fact more than half of the grid is without nodes, which is why Im currently using a dictionary to store node information.

The grid can have several sizes, being 100x100 in the most extreme cases.

There can be several stationary and moving lights, but there will never be more than 30 at the same time, which could be pretty close to each other, as it depends on user input.

Comment: Do you have many light sources? Is your grid large? Do you check whether a cell is lit significantly more often than you create, destroy or move light sources? These things will probably play a role in finding out  which approach is the most efficient. Your idea to keep a count of lights for each cell doesn't sound bad and it shouldn't clutter the code if you take care not to count any cells more than once.

Comment: I'll add the mentioned details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only really see two choices - I think you realise that calculating which nodes should be switched off when a lightsource goes out is too heavy. So the remaining choices:

1. When a light goes out, recalculate all lit nodes from scratch (and when a light goes on, you can continue to update without recalculating the whole).
2. As you suggested, track how many nodes are lighting each given node.

I think the second suggestion is the winner, especially if you recast your mental model - imagine each node has two properties: `lightsource` which is true or false, and `lightlevel` which is an int. You can update `lightsource` on the settable nodes. And `lightlevel` will track how many nodes are casting light on this node. When the level is 1 or greater, it is *lit* in your phrasing from the question. (And, I imagine, each settable node also adds 1 to it's own `lightlevel` when `lightsource` is set to true).

Depending on what you are modelling, you may even be able to use this extra information to your benefit... like if you are modelling actual visual light, you can have nodes with higher `lightlevel` appear differently, etc.

Comment: I finally implemented it, so when the light is activated, the light stores the affected nodes, so when the light is turn off, the nodes are called without recalculating the affected nodes. Even if I lighted a node twice by accident, when turning it of, the node would be left with its original status, as the node would be stored twice in the light's information. if you add this part to your answer (and your own input if you have any) I'll set the answer as correct. So others have all info packed in one answer :)